# Uncaught ReferenceError when adding an EventListener

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to independently implement the ability to drag a block through a class. However getting a problem when trying to overlay an eventListener...

```
class Form {
    constructor() {
        //pass
    }
    DOMGenerator(elemClass) {
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.classList.add(elemClass);
        return element;
    }
    Draw() {
        const form = this.DOMGenerator('window'),
            label = this.DOMGenerator('window_label'),
            controls = this.DOMGenerator('window_controls'),
            close = this.DOMGenerator('close'),
            minimize = this.DOMGenerator('minimize'),
            maximize = this.DOMGenerator('maximize')

            label.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
                const offsetX = event.offsetX;
                const offsetY = event.offsetY;
        
                document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener = event => {
                    let pageX = event.pageX;
                    let pageY = event.pageY;
            
                    form.style.left = `${pageX - offsetX}px`;
                    form.style.top = `${pageY - offsetY}px`;
                })
        
                document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener, false);
                })
            })
        
            controls.append(close, minimize, maximize);
            label.append(controls);
            form.append(label);
            document.body.append(form);
    }
}

new Form().Draw();
```

When executing the code and click on label element I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: listener is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:31:63)
(anonymous) @ main.js:31
```

However, if I execute code OUTSIDE the class on an existing DOM element, then everything works as it should... So then I tried to change function declaration like this

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function listener(event) {
                    let pageX = event.pageX;
                    let pageY = event.pageY;
                
                    form.style.left = `${pageX - offsetX}px`;
                    form.style.top = `${pageY - offsetY}px`;
                })
```

It grabs the window and sticks it to the cursor, but fails to execute removeEventListener with the same error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: listener is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:31:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined a function named listener anywhere.

You can define a `listener` function outside.

```
const listener = (event) => {
   // some code
}

element.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
element.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
```

Here you are just defining a [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#named_function_expression). You cannot access from outside with the name of the listener.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function listener(event) {
 let pageX = event.pageX;
 let pageY = event.pageY;
            
 form.style.left = `${pageX - offsetX}px`;
 form.style.top = `${pageY - offsetY}px`;
})
```

Let's try to access it. The result we will see is `undefined`.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function listener(event) {
      ...
})
    
console.log(typeof listener); -> undefined
```

You can do something like below for the solution.

```
Draw() {
      const form = ...

          let pageX;
          let pageY;
          let offsetX;
          let offsetY;

          const listener = (event) => {
                  pageX = event.pageX;
                  pageY = event.pageY;
          
                  form.style.left = `${pageX - offsetX}px`;
                  form.style.top = `${pageY - offsetY}px`;
          }

          label.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
              offsetX = event.offsetX;
              offsetY = event.offsetY;
      
              document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener)
      
              document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener, false);
              })
          })

         ...
}
```